# ValueError when passing list to __init__ method

Tags: python, python-2.7

In the following code, when i try to send a list in `__init__` method it gives 
`Line 13: ValueError: expecting Array or iterable`

```
class Ball:
    def __init__(self, c, r):
        self.center = c
        self.radius = r

    def move(self, move_vector):
        """Changes the position of the ball by the given vector."""
        self.center[0] += move_vector[0]
        self.center[1] += move_vector[1]



#This line gives error
balls = Ball(list(1,1),1);
balls.move((2,3))
print balls
```

But when i change it to following it works,

```
class Ball:
    def __init__(self, c, r):
        #Changed from c to list(c)
        self.center = list(c)
        self.radius = r

    def move(self, move_vector):
        """Changes the position of the ball by the given vector."""
        self.center[0] += move_vector[0]
        self.center[1] += move_vector[1]



#Changed
balls = Ball((1,1),1);
balls.move((2,3))
print balls
```

I am in process of learning this language, please tell me why is it like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List takes one argument, in the line:

```
balls = Ball(list(1,1),1)
```

You provide list(1,1) with two arguments.

Hth.

Comment: oh i get it, it should be like list((1,1)).